Safari 18 macOS long pauses due to "Queued" time. What means?
I've noticed that Safari 18 sometimes has long pauses loading new websites, but they eventually load.  It may take longer than 20 seconds for it to really start loading.  I was able to capture such a case in the Safari web inspector timing view for the home page of a web site.
In this case the browser is spending 25 seconds in the "Queued" state before it even starts loading anything.  What is the "Queued" state?  I don't think I have many other tabs open, and this resource is the home page of the given site.  Once the Queued state clears, the site loads almost immediately.
I am not using iCloud Private Relay.  This is under macOS 15.1.

